# Cylinder Model with Java and openGL not working as expected

Tags: java, opengl, jframe, computational-geometry, jogl

I have this code for displaying two figures using their classes Scylinder and SSphere. However,only the sphere is displayed on the screen and no errors are shown. Any ideas why it displays only the first object and skips the second but no errors are shown? Thank you in advance.I am a beginner and have no idea where my mistake is.

This is my code for a cylinder:

```
package Objects;


public class SCylinder extends SObject{
private float radius;
private int slices;
private int stacks;

public SCylinder(){ 
    super();
    init();
    update();
}

public SCylinder(float radius){
    super();
    init();
    this.radius = radius;
    update();
}

public SCylinder(float radius, int slices, int stacks){
    super();
    this.radius = radius;
    this.slices = slices;
    this.stacks = stacks;
    update();
}

private void init(){
    this.radius = 1;
    this.slices = 20;
    this.stacks = 20;
}

@Override
protected void genData() {
        int i,j,k;
            // stacks = no. of Latitude lines,
                              // slices = no. of Longitude lines
            numVertices = 10000; 

            //double deltaLong = PI * 2 / slices;
            //double deltaLat = PI / stacks;


            //numVertices = (slices + 1) * (stacks - 1) + 2;
             vertices = new float[numVertices * 3];
             normals = new float[numVertices * 3];
            //textures = new float[numVertices * 2];


            int theta = 0;
                        // vertices body 
              k = 1; 
              for (i = 0; i < slices; i++) { 
                 normals[3 * k] = cos(theta * i); 
                 normals[3 * k + 1] = sin(theta * i); 
                 normals[3 * k + 2] = 0; 

                 vertices[3 * k] = radius * normals[3 * k]; 
                 vertices[3 * k + 1] = radius * normals[3 * k + 1]; 
                 vertices[3 * k + 2] = .50f; 
                 k++; 
               // end of for vertices on body 
              }
              for (i = 0; i < slices; i++) { 
                 normals[3 * k] = cos(theta * i); 
                 normals[3 * k + 1] = sin(theta * i); 
                 normals[3 * k + 2] = 0; 

                 vertices[3 * k] = radius * normals[3 * k]; 
                 vertices[3 * k + 1] = radius * normals[3 * k + 1]; 
                 vertices[3 * k + 2] = -.50f; 

                 k++; 
              } // end of for vertices on body 

                    // Generate indices for triangular mesh 
             numIndices = 100000; 
             indices = new  int[numIndices]; 

            k = 0; 

            for (i = 0; i < slices; ++i) {

                 int i1 = i; 
                 int i2 = (i1 + 1) % slices; 
                 int i3 = i1 + slices; 
                 int i4 = i2 + slices; 

                 indices[k++] = i1; 
                 indices[k++] = i3; 
                 indices[k++] = i2;


                 indices[k++] = i4; 
                 indices[k++] = i2; 
                 indices[k++] = i3;


            }






public void setRadius(float radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    updated = false;
}

public void setSlices(int slices){
    this.slices = slices;
    updated = false;
}

public void setStacks(int stacks){
    this.stacks = stacks;
    updated = false;
}

public float getRadius(){
    return radius;
}

public int getSlices(){
    return slices;
}

public int getStacks(){
    return stacks;
}   
 }
```

**The next part is the main file:**

```
public class CGCW02 extends JFrame{

final GLCanvas canvas; //Define a canvas 
final FPSAnimator animator=new FPSAnimator(60, true);
final Renderer renderer = new Renderer();

public CGCW02() {
    GLProfile glp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
    canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

    add(canvas, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER); // Put the canvas in the frame
    canvas.addGLEventListener(renderer); //Set the canvas to listen GLEvents

    animator.add(canvas);

    setTitle("Coursework 2");
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    animator.start();
    canvas.requestFocus();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
             new CGCW02();

}

class Renderer implements GLEventListener {

    private Transform T = new Transform(); //model_view transform

    //VAOs and VBOs parameters
    private int idPoint=0, numVAOs = 2;
    private int idBuffer=0, numVBOs = 2;
    private int idElement=0, numEBOs = 2;
    private int[] VAOs = new int[numVAOs];
    private int[] VBOs = new int[numVBOs];
    private int[] EBOs = new int[numEBOs];

    //Model parameters
    private int[] numElements = new int[numEBOs];
    private long vertexSize; 
    private long normalSize; 
    private int vPosition;
    private int vNormal;

    //Transformation parameters
    private int ModelView;
    private int NormalTransform;
    private int Projection; 

    //Lighting parameter
    private int AmbientProduct;
    private int DiffuseProduct;
    private int SpecularProduct;            
    private int Shininess;

    private float[] ambient1; 
            private float[] diffuse1;
            private float[] specular1;
            private float  materialShininess1;

    private float[] ambient2; 
            private float[] diffuse2;
            private float[] specular2;
            private float  materialShininess2;

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3(); // Get the GL pipeline object this 

        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    //gl.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        //Transformation for the first object (sphere)
        T.initialize();
        T.scale(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
                    T.rotateX(-90);
        T.translate(0, -0.4f, 0);


        //Locate camera
        T.lookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 1, 0);     //Default                   

        //Send model_view and normal transformation matrices to shader. 
        //Here parameter 'true' for transpose means to convert the row-major  
        //matrix to column major one, which is required when vertices'
        //location vectors are pre-multiplied by the model_view matrix.
        //Note that the normal transformation matrix is the inverse-transpose
        //matrix of the vertex transformation matrix
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv( ModelView, 1, true, T.getTransformv(), 0 );          
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv( NormalTransform, 1, true, T.getInvTransformTv(), 0 );            

        //send other uniform variables to shader
        gl.glUniform4fv( AmbientProduct, 1, ambient1,0 );
                    gl.glUniform4fv( DiffuseProduct, 1, diffuse1, 0 );
                    gl.glUniform4fv( SpecularProduct, 1, specular1, 0 );            
                    gl.glUniform1f( Shininess, materialShininess1);

        //binding and draw the first object
        idPoint=0;
        idBuffer=0;
        idElement=0;
        bindObject(gl);
            gl.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numElements[idElement], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);    

        //Add code here to transform the second object (a cylinder) into the position
        //as suggested in the coursework description, and draw it

                    T.scale(0.5f, 1.4f,0.5f);
                    T.translate(10, 0.7f, 0);

        //binding and draw the second object
        idPoint=1;
        idBuffer=1;
        idElement=1;
                    bindObject(gl);     

        gl.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numElements[idElement], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);    //for solid sphere      
    }       

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3(); // Get the GL pipeline object this 

        System.out.print("GL_Version: " + gl.glGetString(GL_VERSION));

        gl.glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 

        //compile and use the shader program
        ShaderProg shaderproc = new ShaderProg(gl, "Gouraud.vert", "Gouraud.frag");
        int program = shaderproc.getProgram();
        gl.glUseProgram(program);

            // Initialize the vertex position and normal attribute in the vertex shader    
        vPosition = gl.glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
        vNormal = gl.glGetAttribLocation( program, "vNormal" );

        // Get connected with the ModelView, NormalTransform, and Projection matrices
        // in the vertex shader
        ModelView = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "ModelView");
        NormalTransform = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "NormalTransform");
        Projection = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "Projection");

        // Get connected with uniform variables AmbientProduct, DiffuseProduct, 
        // SpecularProduct, and Shininess in the vertex shader          
        AmbientProduct = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "AmbientProduct");
        DiffuseProduct = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "DiffuseProduct");
        SpecularProduct = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "SpecularProduct");          
        Shininess = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "Shininess");

        // Generate VAOs, VBOs, and EBOs
            gl.glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs,VAOs,0);
        gl.glGenBuffers(numVBOs, VBOs,0);
        gl.glGenBuffers(numEBOs, EBOs,0);

        // Initialize shader lighting parameters
        float[] lightPosition = {10.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f, 1.0f};
        Vec4 lightAmbient = new Vec4(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        Vec4 lightDiffuse = new Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Vec4 lightSpecular = new Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glUniform4fv( gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "LightPosition"),
              1, lightPosition, 0 );

        //create the first object: a sphere-----------------------------------
        SObject sphere = new SSphere(1,40,40);
        idPoint=0;
        idBuffer=0;
        idElement=0;
        createObject(gl, sphere);


        // Set Sphere material
        Vec4 materialAmbient1 = new Vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Vec4 materialDiffuse1 = new Vec4(0.7f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Vec4 materialSpecular1 = new Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        materialShininess1 = 64.0f;

        Vec4 ambientProduct = lightAmbient.times(materialAmbient1);
        ambient1 = ambientProduct.getVector();
        Vec4 diffuseProduct = lightDiffuse.times(materialDiffuse1);
        diffuse1 = diffuseProduct.getVector();
        Vec4 specularProduct = lightSpecular.times(materialSpecular1);
        specular1 = specularProduct.getVector();

                //Create the second object (a cylinder) here, and set the ----------------------- 
        //cylinder material different to the sphere
                //Vertices below are in Clockwise orientation
                //Default setting for glFrontFace is Counter-clockwise


                   SObject cylinder = new SCylinder(20,40,40);
                    idPoint=1;
        idBuffer=1;
        idElement=1;
        createObject (gl,cylinder);

                    // Set Cylinder's material
        Vec4 materialAmbient2 = new Vec4(0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f, 0.55f);
        Vec4 materialDiffuse2 = new Vec4(0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f, 0.55f);
        Vec4 materialSpecular2 = new Vec4(0.633f, 0.727f, 0.633f, 0.55f);
        materialShininess1 = 76.8f;

        Vec4 ambientProduct2= lightAmbient.times(materialAmbient2);
        ambient2 = ambientProduct2.getVector();
        Vec4 diffuseProduct2 = lightDiffuse.times(materialDiffuse2);
        diffuse2 = diffuseProduct2.getVector();
        Vec4 specularProduct2 = lightSpecular.times(materialSpecular2);
        specular2 = specularProduct2.getVector();


        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);         
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w,
            int h) {

        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3(); // Get the GL pipeline object this 

        gl.glViewport(x, y, w, h);

        T.initialize();

        //projection
        if(h<1){h=1;}
        if(w<1){w=1;}           
        float a = (float) w/ h;   //aspect 
        if (w < h) {
            T.ortho(-1, 1, -1/a, 1/a, -1, 1);
        }
        else{
            T.ortho(-1*a, 1*a, -1, 1, -1, 1);
        }

        // Convert right-hand to left-hand coordinate system
        T.reverseZ();
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv( Projection, 1, true, T.getTransformv(), 0 );         

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void createObject(GL3 gl, SObject obj) {
        float [] vertexArray = obj.getVertices();
        float [] normalArray = obj.getNormals();
        int [] vertexIndexs =obj.getIndices();
        numElements[idElement] = obj.getNumIndices();

        bindObject(gl);

        FloatBuffer vertices = FloatBuffer.wrap(vertexArray);
        FloatBuffer normals = FloatBuffer.wrap(normalArray);

                    // Create an empty buffer with the size we need 
        // and a null pointer for the data values

        vertexSize = vertexArray.length*(Float.SIZE/0x8);
        normalSize = normalArray.length*(Float.SIZE/0x8);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize +normalSize, 
                null, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // pay attention to *Float.SIZE/8

        // Load the real data separately.  We put the colors right after the vertex coordinates,
        // so, the offset for colors is the size of vertices in bytes
        gl.glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexSize, vertices );
        gl.glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, normalSize, normals );

        IntBuffer elements = IntBuffer.wrap(vertexIndexs);          

        long indexSize = vertexIndexs.length*(Integer.SIZE/8);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexSize, 
                elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // pay attention to *Float.SIZE/8                        
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vNormal);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(vNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexSize);
    }

    public void bindObject(GL3 gl){
        gl.glBindVertexArray(VAOs[idPoint]);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[idBuffer]);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBOs[idElement]);          
    };
}
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I advise you to understand the code you posted. If your object is outside of your view frustum (look at the model-view matrix equivalent in your shader based example), it won't be visible.